# IBM Quantum computer code keeps running job after job

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm using qiskit for my University research project but whenever I send a job to run on IBM's Quantum experience, it'll wait in the queue, run, obtain results (in the form of a histogram) but instead of moving to the next part of the code (analyzing the results), it'll join the back of the queue to be ran again. This creates a new job to be ran, obtains results, and joins the back of the queue. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue, or know how to resolve it?

I should state I'm not using any loops in my code (whether for or otherwise), and I'm mainly focused on the chemistry aspect of qiskit (Ground State Eigen Solvers and VQEUCCSDFactory)

Comment: Would need to see the code to have a better idea of what might be going on.

Comment: `from qiskit import BasicAer`
`from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance`
`from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers.minimum_eigensolver_factories import VQEUCCSDFactory`
`vqe_solver = VQEUCCSDFactory(QuantumInstance(provider.get_backend('ibmq_valencia')))`
'from qiskit.chemistry.algorithms.ground_state_solvers import GroundStateEigensolver'
`res = GroundStateEigensolver(transformation, vqe_solver).solve(driver)`

There is the end of my code, the initial part isn't causing the problem as I've attempted a different way and still have the same problem (see other comment)